# How to change chartist CSS

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

i'm trying to change some chartist CSS to have the labels above the bars with color.
Somes changes works fine, for example:

```
.ct-label {
  color: white;
}
```

But other changes doesn't work:

```
.ct-label-above {
  color: white;
}
```

don't.
I can change font-size or font-weight for .ct-label-above but change color doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtDeB.png)

Maybe i'm missing something.
I create a codepen for this:

https://codepen.io/wolverine4277/pen/XWXxqwa

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember that part of the styling was in the JS elements. You may look at the doc's https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#customizing-the-default-css. I remeber having hard time & not fully happy with the final result...

Comment: Thanks @Mulli, i look the docs but and  finally change chartist for chartjs, more flexible and easy to styling!